# Why is java.util.regex.Matcher start() and end() returning extra characters in this case?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm generating some regexes dynamically and replacing the matched results with another string post-hoc in my application. I'm taking the start and end indices of a match then replacing each matched chunk of characters one by one and then adjusting the offsets for the next matches. However in one match out of other several successfully matched/replaced cases I noticed that my start and end indices include an extra character.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the regexes:

```
Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+(?<match>" + Pattern.quote(search[i]) + ")[^a-zA-Z]+")
```

Where in the case that's adding an extra character

```
search[i] = "on a daily basis"
```

The resulting regex

```
[^a-zA-Z]+(?<match>\Qon a daily basis\E)[^a-zA-Z]+
```

This is the relevant text that's being matched against

```
to on a daily basis.
```

My desired output is

```
on a daily basis
```

This is the output I get from matcher.group("match"), however when I debug the start() and end() results from the same matcher context I get 356 and 375 respectively (this is in the context of the full text), but you can see that the difference between those two numbers is 19 while the string "on a daily basis" is only 16 characters.

I'm assuming that I need to account for the \Q and \E from Pattern.quote? But then where is the third extra additional character coming from? And why does this only occur in this pattern/target string case specifically?

Is there some other unrelated cause of the discrepancy that I'm overlooking?

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, just to make it easier to experiment.

Comment: You're not counting the `[^a-zA-Z]+` at the beginning and end. Those are included in actual match.

Comment: @RohitJain: Not for `matcher.group("match")`. This is why I want to see a short but complete example :)

Comment: @JonSkeet That will give the the pattern in the `group`, but `start()` and `end()` would consider the complete match, AFAIK.

Comment: @RohitJain: Whoops - had forgotten that `group` doesn't return an object representing the group (as in .NET) but just the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is as expected. You didn't consider the `[^a-zA-Z]+` at the start and end of your pattern. So, though the length of actual text is `16`, total length of matched string would be different.

Though the [`Matcher#group(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(java.lang.String)) will return the text matched in that group, the [`Matcher#start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start()) will give the start index of the complete match. Same for `end()` method. It will give index of 1 past the last index of matched string.

If you want to get start and end index of matched group, you can pass the group name to both `start(String)` and `end(String)` method.

Try this out in a small string, and you'll get to know.

```
String search = "on a daily basis";
String toMatch = "to on a daily basis. ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+(?<match>" + Pattern.quote(search) + ")[^a-zA-Z]+");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toMatch);

if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group().length());
  System.out.println(matcher.start());
  System.out.println(matcher.end());

  System.out.println(matcher.group("match").length());
  System.out.println(matcher.start("match")); // your expected result
  System.out.println(matcher.end("match")); 
}
```

So in above example, the length of group is different from the length of complete match (which is what you get as result).

Comment: Possibly mention the options of `matcher.start("match")` and `matcher.end("match")`?

Comment: I see. Thanks. To fix my problem I changed my regex to `[^a-zA-Z](?<match>\Qon a daily basis\E)[^a-zA-Z]` and used start+1 and end-1 to retrieve the relevant text.

Comment: @blend You can get index of matched group instead, see updated answer.